# Java Regular Expression Pattern Matching

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to create a regular expression, in Java, that will match the following:

*A*B

where A and B are ANY character except asterisk, and there can be any number of A characters and B characters. A(s) is/are preceded by asterisk, and B(s) is/are preceded by asterisk.

Will the following work? Seems to work when I run it, but I want to be absolutely sure.

```
Pattern.matches("\\A\\*([^\\*]{1,})\\*([^\\*]{1,})\\Z", someString)
```

Comment: Just added my answer assuming you didn't want a match on `*ABC*DEF` or `*A_$-123*B<>+-321`. Have a look at my answer please.

Comment: I want a match on both *AAA*BBB and *ABC*DEF. I do not know what characters and how many will be between the stars, nor their pattern. I only know that the characters cannot be asterisk as I am using it to split the string (for example *AAA*BBB, I would have two strings AAA and BBB, or *ABC*DEF I would have ABC and DEF

Answer (score 3):

It will work, however you can rewrite it as this (unquoted):

```
\A\*([^*]+)\*([^*]+)\Z
```

- there is no need to quote the star in a character class;
- `{1,}` and `+` are the same quantifier (once or more).

Note 1: you use `.matches()` which automatically anchors the regex at the beginning and end; you may therefore do without `\A` and `\Z`.

Note 2: I have retained the capturing groups -- do you actually need them?

Note 3: it is unclear whether you want *the same* character repeated between the stars; the example above assumes not. If you want the same, then use this:

```
\A\*(([^*])\2*)\*(([^*])\4*)\Z
```

Comment: Do you need to escape the asterisk within the square brackets as [^\\*]?

Comment: No you don't. A star/asterisk is not special within a character class, as I mentioned.

Comment: This would fail to prevent a match on something like `*A_$-123*B<>+-321`.

Comment: Yes indeed, but the op doesn't explicitly say that the characters inbetween the stars have to be the _same_. If this is the case, the initial question should be edited. (edited answer to mention 2nd solution)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correct.. it can be as simple as

```
^\\*((?!\\*).)+\\*((?!\\*).)+
```

Comment: No: the dot will capture any character, including the star, and the OP wants anytiing but the star.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a match on `*AAA*BBB` but not on `*ABC*DEF` use

```
^\*([a-zA-Z])\1*\*([a-zA-Z])\2*$
```

This won't match on this either

```
*A_$-123*B<>+-321
```